# I run uninstall.sh but "command not found", what more I can do?

Tags: uninstall

I tried to install Packet Tracer 7.1 with a `.run` method but it didn't work. So now, I'm trying to uninstall it with `uninstall.sh`, but I get this error:

[image: terminal output]

```
user@ideapad:/opt/pt$ ./uninstall.sh
sudo: ./uninstall.sh: command not found
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you have to make it executable: `chmod +x uninstall.sh`

Comment: `sudo sh uninstall.sh`

Comment: I ran `chmod +x uninstall.sh` and `./uninstall.sh` but the Packet Tracker icon appears yet.

Comment: The same with `sudo sh uninstall.sh`, the icon appears yet

Comment: You need root rights to make `uninstall.sh` executable and then run it. So you have to run `sudo chmod +x uninstall.sh` and then `sudo ./uninstall.sh` or just run @Pilot6's command.

Comment: Yes, I ran the commands with root rights.

Comment: Please run `ls -al` in that directory and post the results so we can make some sense of this situation. Also run `sudo -l` and post that too!

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with uninstallin Code42/Crashplan. First Ubuntu 20.04 went fine, but second gave same error as you had. I just changed the permissions of the uninstall.sh
file to "Allow executing file as program" in Nautilus and everything went fine
after.

cd ~/Downloads/code42-install

sudo ./uninstall.sh -i /usr/local/crashplan